# returnurl() always return index.php in yii

Tags: yii, yii-modules

I created a module Admin in yii.

If I request any page in this module before login it will redirect to login page. But after successful login it rediect to the site/index. This is the code for redirection.

```
if($model->validate() && $model->login())
{
    $this->redirect( Yii::app()->user->returnUrl );
}
```

when I print `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl`, it shows `/`

thanking you for help.

Comment: and what is your question? The default return URL for a user after login is the `site/index` (controller/action), which is the same the URL path `/`

Comment: check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19100-directing-a-user-to-last-page-accessed/page__p__93559__hl__redirect+la+t#entry93559)